# Making AsyncTasks to run automatically

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a list containing URLs of Images that I want to download with Android's DownloadManager. It's a pretty basic design to define a AsyncTask subclass that removes an object from the list and then invokes the DownloadManager. My problem is how to handle the parallelism of the AsyncTasks when each of those will `list.get(curentIndex)`. To make things clear I want each Task (which will be running on the Executor so running in parallel amongst the others not only the Main Thread) to run **atomically** the action that

1. will remove the objects from the lists
2. will and increment the index

Comment: Why not simply wrap the invocation of the AsyncTask in a synchronized method, with proper locks, to make it essentially atomical?

Comment: well that is what I want actually, but I do not know how to do it properly. I mean Java-wise I've only used AsyncTasks for parallelism not java threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in general a synchronization problem. There are many ways to tackle this. I would suggest something along the lines:

```
// Your index. Defaulted at 0. Thread safe Integer wrapper object.
// All set/get operations are guaranteed atomical.
AtomicInteger mIndex = new AtomicInteger(0);

// Your list. This is thread-safe. All mutative operations
// are atomical, and properly locked. The list is copied on each write.
// This solution, though it does what it needs to do, is SLOW. Don't use for
// large lists.
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Object> mList = ... ;

// Your async task. Maybe more of them.
AsyncTask mTask = ...;

// Anything here that should be thread safe.
ensurePrerequisites(mTask);

// Execute on thread pool to make sure they're parallel.
// CAUTION: You will still get only (CPU_CORE_COUNT + 1) max parallel tasks.
mTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);


public void synchronized ensurePrerequisites(AsyncTask task) {
     // I assume you want to pass the values into the task.
     int idx = mIndex.getAndIncrement();
     task.setIndex(idx);
     task.setObject(mList.remove(idx));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a well documented answer it really helps me start and continue on my own.I'm really grateful!

Comment: I guess that mList.remove(idx) is a mList.get(idx) right?

Comment: Removes essentially removes the element from the list and returns it. The same as get, just it additionally removes the element permanently

Comment: Since we increment the index we can't use remove cause we'll lose elements. I'm just saying it so that you can edit it :)